# Passing custom arguments to Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scheduled-tasks, sidekiq, sidetiq

I have a Rails app that requires the user to pass in input that defines how frequently an action is scheduled (e.g one month, three months, six months, etc.) I'm using Sidekiq to run backup jobs, and integrated Sidetiq for the scheduling. As it turns out (something I realized only after integrating it fully), Sidekiq has problems with recurring tasks that initially require custom input. It will run fine the first time, but when it comes up to run three months later, the arguments the method has are (time_last_run, time_of_next_run) and this is a problem for me because I need some user details passed into the recurring action. This is discussed by Sidekiq's author in this issue from a few years ago: https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq/issues/37

This leaves me rather lost. This is my first Rails app, and I'm not sure how else to perform recurring background tasks with user input. As you can see, the Sidetiq issue still hasn't been resolved, and I'm not sure of any valid alternatives. Does anyone know how I can write a workaround for this? Put another way, how else could I implement this functionality (with or without Sidetiq)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to run a job after some fixed duration. This could be achieved with `Sidekiq.perform_in` method, you need to pass time in seconds as first param and then rest all params as you normally pass.

Hope this is what you are looking for.